# How to plot a heatmap using plt.imshow() from pandas dataset X and Y co-ordinates?

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, imshow

I want to plot a heatmap using XY co-ordinates I have attached below. ( I have them in a CSV file originally).
I am unable to combine the two data frame columns into a valid shape for Image.
plt.imshow(Z) takes only one argument for image data and I am unable to combine two columns into one.
So, how to plot a heatmap using plt.imshow() in python?

[X,Y coordinates here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VeW814nYafCo8snOI0hTVdeRfIAj0Eplkl5cu3G5xqk/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try with `np.histogram2d`:

```
hist, xe, ye = np.histogram2d(df['X'], df['Y'])
plt.imshow(hist, origin='lower')
```

Output (you will need to relabel the ticks)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Other than np.histogram2d() are there any other methods for the same?